# Accessing derived class property members from base class object in CSharp

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am having trouble accessing property members of derived class using base class object.

Scenario:

```
public class BaseClass{
    public virtual Write(BaseClass data){
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass{

    private string name:

    public string Name {get {return name} set {name = value;} }

    public override Write(BaseClass data){
     Console.println(data.Name);  // gives me error here
    }

}
```

Comment: Name is never defined in BaseClass.

Comment: You can not do that, you can not expect the `BaseClass data` to be of the same type as `DerivedClass`. What do you expect it to print?

Comment: Also, `Console.println` does not exist. `Console.WriteLine` do.

Comment: The BaseCLass doesn't have a Name property. That would be the derived class. Seems you have a few more errors in your code. Is this visual studio? private string name: should have a ;. return name should end with ;. Console has no println. WriteLine would be it. etc

Answer (score 6):

The reason you have a problem accessing properties in derived classes is that the base class does not (and more importantly *should not*) know anything about them. Different derived classes could have a different set of added properties. Making the base class aware of this would counteract important principles of object oriented design. One such principle that comes to mind is the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Answer (score 0):

As stated, name does not exists in the BaseClass.

Either move "name" to the base class or create a separate Write Method that writes the inherited class's specific data.

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override void Write(DerivedClass data) {
        Console.printLn(data.Name);
        base.Write(data)
    }

    // why print a different instance, just write self
    public void Write() {
        Console.printLn(this.Name);
        base.Write(this)
    }

}
```

Not sure why the Class would accept a different Class Instance to write when you can just invoke write on itself.   Change the BaseClass signture to

```
public virtual Write()
```

or like WebControls

```
public virtual Write(HtmlTextWriter writer);
```

if you want simply debugging, you could just serialize to JSON or XML and then output that to your console