# Can we access derived class properties by using base class object?

Tags: c#, inheritance

Can we access derived class properties by using base class object?

I am having a base class

```
 public abstract class FnmaRecord
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }            
        public abstract String Prefix
        {
            get;
        }
    }
```

And there are many derived classes which inherits the FnmaRecord class

```
 public class TransactionHeader : FnmaRecord
    {
        public override string Prefix { get {return "TH";} }

        public static readonly string TransactionId = "T100099-002";

        public String TransactionControlNumber { get; set; }

    }


public class TitleHolder : FnmaRecord
    {
        public override string Prefix { get {return "02C";} }

        public string TitleHolderName { get; set; }
    }
```

Now can i use the instance of the FnmaRecord in another class to access the property in TitleHolder?

Comment: Sorry your question is not clear, what do you want to do?

Comment: Given a variable of the base class, the only property you should be accessing is Prefix. Otherwise the code is wrong wrong wrong.

Answer (score 5):

No. As Fredrik Mörk states in [their answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329276/accessing-derived-class-property-members-from-base-class-object-in-csharp/4329334#4329334):

> Base class does not (and more importantly should not) know anything
>   about derived class properties. Different derived classes could have a different set of
>   added properties. Making the base class aware of this would counteract
>   important principles of object oriented design

Answer (score 1):

No. You just create an instance of TitleHolder on the class where you want to put FnmaRecord instance, so that you can access both the properties of TitleHolder and FnmaRecord.