# C# base class method can not read instance attribute which is in derived class

Tags: c#, python, oop

```
using System;

class BaseClass
{

    public string name;

    public BaseClass()
    {
        this.name = "MyName";
    }

    public virtual void A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.surname); // error. BaseClass does not definition of surname
    }

}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public string surname;

    public DerivedClass()
    {
        this.surname = "MySurname";
    }
}

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DerivedClass dc = new DerivedClass();
            dc.A();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain this to me? I know that `BaseClass` does not contain the definition of `surname`, but I am calling `A()` method from `DerivedClass`     object (`this.surname` - `this` is an object of `DerivedClass`). `DerivedClass` object contains information about `name` and `surname`! Why it is impossible to access `surname` from `A()` method? This is very interesting for me because in Python this model works perfectly. Code is below.

```
class BaseClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'MyName'

    def a(self):
        print(self.surname)

class DerivedClass(BaseClass):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.surname = 'MySurname'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dc = DerivedClass()
    dc.a()
```

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: There are fundamental differences in python and c#. In Python, attributes are resolved at run-time, C# at compile time. 
I think its also bad design because it is not a great idea for a parent class to make assumptions about its child classes like that.

Comment: `BaseClass` doesn't know **at compile time** what `surname` refers to. That is the answer. **You** know, at **runtime**, that there will be an object of a type that inherits from `BaseClass` that **does** have a `surname` property. But that is not known at **compile time**. So - it doesn't compile.

Comment: Good answers. Thank you !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing derived class property members from base class object in CSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329276/accessing-derived-class-property-members-from-base-class-object-in-csharp)

Answer (score 3):

The `surname` field is only available in the Derived class, you should override the virtual method in your derived class:

```
using System;

class BaseClass
{

    public string name;

    public BaseClass()
    {
        this.name = "MyName";
    }

    public virtual void A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hi {name}, I don't know your surname here");
    }

}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public string surname;

    public DerivedClass()
    {
        this.surname = "MySurname";
    }

   // HERE:
    public override void A()
    {
        // the 'this' and 'base' are just for clarification and are optional.
        Console.WriteLine($"Hi {base.name} {this.surname}, how are you.");
    }
}

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DerivedClass dc = new DerivedClass();
            dc.A();

            // It's even possible to store the derived class in a base class variable
            BaseClass bc = new DerivedClass();
            bc.A(); // it will still execute the overriden method.

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your baseClass isn't necessary inherited by a class having the surname property.

As mentionned J. van Langen, you still can declare classes using their base class

```
using System;

class BaseClass
{
    public string name;

    public BaseClass()
    {
        this.name = "MyName";
    }

    public virtual void A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Looks like I have no surname");
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public string surname;

    public DerivedClass()
    {
        this.surname = "MySurname";
    }

    public override void A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.surname);
    }
}

class AnotherDerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public string IHaveNoSurname;

    public AnotherDerivedClass()
    {
        this.IHaveNoSurname = "Well, no surname for me...";
    }
}

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<BaseClass> MyClasses = new List<BaseClass>();
            MyClasses.Add(new DerivedClass());
            MyClasses.Add(new AnotherDerivedClass());

            foreach (BaseClass MyClasse in MyClasses)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(MyClasse.GetType());
                MyClasse.A();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

> DerivedClass
>
> MySurname
>
> AnotherDerivedClass
>
> Looks like I have no surname